# Can Docker containers in a single swarm stack be isolated from each other?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I would like to have a single Docker stack, with 4 services:

- a1
- a2
- b1
- b2

The `a` services should be able to communicate with each other over the network/HTTP, as should the `b` services. But the `a` services should be isolated from the `b` services in terms of network access.

By default, in Docker Swarm, are all services in a Stack placed on a common network? If I have a stack.yml file that looks like this:

```
networks:
  a:
    name: a
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
  b:
    name: b
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true

services:
  a1:
    networks:
      - a
  a2:
    networks:
      - a
  b1:
    networks:
      - b
  b2:
    networks:
      - b
```

Are the "a" services isolated from the "b" services? If not, can this be achieved without using separate stacks?

Comment: As long as you define at least one network in a stack, docker will not generate the default network for the given stack. So you should be good on that end.

But note docker itself has an ICC property, which may alter the behaviour (--icc                                   Enable inter-container communication (default true)) - reference  (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/)

Comment: > As long as you define at least one network in a stack, docker will not generate the default network for the given stack.
Not quite true. docker will generate the default network if any one service requires it. A service with no networks is an implicit reference, and you can explicitly reference it as `default`

Answer (score 1):

you could use an ssh server as a bastion, and map ports to/from the bastion

```
networks:
  a:
    name: a
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
  b:
    name: b
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true

services:
  a1:
    networks:
      - a
  a2:
    networks:
      - a
  b1:
    networks:
      - b
  b2:
    networks:
      - b
  bastion:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/openssh-server:latest
    environment:
      - USER_PASSWORD=letmein
      - USER_NAME=bastion-user
    ports:
      - '2222:2222'
    networks:
      - a
      - b
```

you would need to run a second process in your other containers to map ports, something like (from a1)

```
ssh bastion-user@bastion -L 1234:b1:1234
```

Comment: I've clarified in the question. I mean communicate in the network sense

Comment: got it, will refine

Comment: Upvote because processing via a 3rd party service such as redis is a need idea!